# linq filter cannot appear after default?

Tags: c#, linq

I have been stymied trying to rewrite a bit of imperative code in LINQ until I realized what I was missing.  But I don't know why this is an issue.  Consider the following.  The test fails running `Test.Test2(testList)` with

> Sequence contains no matching elements

In the past, I've treated these forms interchangeably, writing code smaller by pushing my predicates to the `First`, `Single`, etc... clauses.  Clearly I cannot do that when a `DeafultIfEmpty` is involved.  Is this because using `Where` and `First`, `Single`, etc are not interchangeable?  Or, is it because the `DefaultIfEmpty` clause introduces a complication?

**edit 1**
I added a test to show that FirstOrDefault does not work.  It fails with "not found" not equal to (null).

```
public static class Test
{
    public static string Test1(params string[] input)
    {
        return input
            .Where(x => x == "apples")
            .DefaultIfEmpty("bannanas")
            .First();
    }

    public static string Test2(params string[] input)
    {
        return input
            .DefaultIfEmpty("bannanas")
            .First(x => x == "apples");
    }

    public static string Test3(params string[] input)
    {
        return input
            .DefaultIfEmpty("bannanas")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x == "apples");
    }
}

public class TestStuff
{
    [Fact]
    public static void TestOneAndTwo()
    {
        var testList = new string[] { "oranges", "pears", "pineapples" };
        var one = Test.Test1(testList);
        var two = Test.Test2(testList);
        Assert.Equal(one, two);
    }

    [Fact]
    public static void TestOneAndThree()
    {
        var testList = new string[] { "oranges", "pears", "pineapples" };
        var one = Test.Test1(testList);
        var three = Test.Test3(testList);
        Assert.Equal(one, three);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the LINQ methods is important, consider what each method does to the input enumerable (`{ "oranges", "pears", "pineapples" }`):

```
public static string Test1(params string[] input)
{
    return input
        .Where(x => x == "apples") // empty enumerable, because no item matches "apples"
        .DefaultIfEmpty("not found") // {"not found"}, since the enumerable is empty
        .First(); //"not found", since we have this item
} 

public static string Test2(params string[] input)
{
    return input
        .DefaultIfEmpty("not found") // { "oranges", "pears", "pineapples" }
                                     //i.e., nothing changes, because input is not empty
        .First(x => x == "apples"); //Exception because there is no
                                    //item that is equal to "apples"
}
```

If you change the last method from `First` to `FirstOrDefault`, that would produce `null` because `default(string)` is `null`.

Comment: This makes sense to me, I had not considered order of operations being important... and I thought DefaultIfEmpty setup a default for later operators to use if they returned nothing.  It behaves as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use `FirstOrDefault()`, so that when the array doesn't any match, a default value is returned, instead of throwing an exception.

---

EDIT:

In the `Test1`, after the `Where` clause, the resulting sequence becomes empty. When `DefaultIfEmpty` is applied, the resulting sequence will contains a single element, `"not found"`.

In the `Test2`, when `DefaultIfEmpty` is applied, the sequence isn't filtered yet. Therefore, the same sequence is passed along. However, when`First(predicate)` tries to reduce the sequence, there is nothing that can come out, which is why `InvalidOperationException` occured.

Comment: That doesn't merit out.  When I use first or default, my "DefaultIfEmpty" is ignored and the function returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Xiaoy312.  The FirstOrDefault method is better.  Then a check to see if its null.

```
public static string Test2(params string[] input)
{
     return input.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "apples")
}
```

Comment: the question isn't what architecture would be better... the example is contrived.  The question is about how DefaultIfEmpty works.  Yacoub's answer wins because he points out "order matters", which I didn't understand.